# Set the rotation and position of bitmap

Tags: java, android, matrix, position, surfaceview

I would like to know how i both can change the position of a bitmap and at the same time rotate it. Im drawing at a canvas.

Im currently using this line of code:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, posX, posY, paint);
```

and I think using a matrix for rotation is the best option? The problem is that the line of code, posted above, doesn't take a matrix but a position.

There is also a similar line of code:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
```

This one takes a matrix but not a position.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix transformation can include both position and rotation (as well as other things) simultaneously. Use methods like [postTranslate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#postTranslate(float,%20float)) to modify the matrix, rather than methods like `setTranslate()`, which reset the matrix before adding the new transformation.

Comment: Thanks man, it seems to be a good solution:)